# How to load my data in dynatree view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, dynatree

I'am developing a web application and i'am using dynatree for structure.

```
EX:
Node 1
 + Node 1.1
   + Node 1.1.1
   + Node 1.1.2
   + Node 1.1.3
```

I want to add child node (+Node 1.1.3.1) in this, like

```
  Node 1
   + Node 1.1
   + Node 1.1.1
   + Node 1.1.2
   + Node 1.1.3
      + Node 1.1.3.1
```

And I got my data in json format and my code is following

```
  var treeData = [];
            var selKeys=[];
            var key=0;




$(function(){
  //alert(roleName);

  $("#tree2").dynatree({         
  checkbox: true,
  selectMode: 3,
  children: treeData,
  minExpandLevel: 2       
});

     $.ajax({
       url: "http://localhost:8080/collection-ui/api/permissions/findall",
       success: function( treeData ) {
           var tree = $("#tree2").dynatree("getTree");
           var rootNode = $("#tree2").dynatree("getRoot");             
           var TopRoot = rootNode.addChild({
                title: 'Select All',
                tooltip:'Select All'
            });

            $.each(treeData, function(key, val){
               var ParentId = val['parentId'];

                   if(ParentId == 0)
                   {    
                       key=val['permissionId'];
                       var childNode = TopRoot.addChild({
                           key: val['permissionId'],
                            title: val['permissionName'],
                            tooltip:val['permissionName']                               
                        });

                   }else{       

                       var node = tree.getNodeByKey("ParentId");                       
                       node.addChild({
                           key: val['permissionId'],
                            title: val['permissionName']
                             tooltip:val['permissionName']  
                        });
                   }          
           });

       }

    }) ;
```

But the else part in my code is not working properly.Is there any wrong ? When i run this program it shows like "node is null"  Pls anybdy help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a comma here

```
title: val['permissionName']
tooltip:val['permissionName']
```

Should be

```
title: val['permissionName'],
tooltip:val['permissionName']
```

Comment: Thank you!! but after correct it, still i have some problem that's....its shows "node is null"     
     |
     node.addChild({         Plz help me

Comment: I think this `tree.getNodeByKey("ParentId")` should be like this `tree.getNodeByKey(ParentId)` shouldn't it?

Comment: tried this also but no changes....Same error thats "node is null" Plz i need ur help....

Comment: Well not to be nasty but your code is a bit a mess ;-) Have you used the debugger? What value did you get on this codeline?

Comment: And ParentId sure has the right key value? I can't help much more because i can't see the html code dynatree has generated.

Comment: Hmm according to the dynatree reference i think you should give the ??`$.each` the `tree` object instead of the `treeData`.

Comment: I got it.We should convert to String , like---> var node = tree.getNodeByKey(ParentId.toString());

Comment: I have one more doubt can you help??  I want to change the URL(url: "http://localhost:8080/collection-ui/api/permissions/findall",).Because this is local host right,so how to change it to independent host?? plz help for this one

Comment: If your page is also on the same host with the same port you can just enter a relative path. So for example if this file is in the folder collection-ui you just change the url to this `url: "api/permissions/findall",`

Comment: If everything works could you please mark my answer as the solution?

Comment: Here some error that's, while inserting the data,response is null and also it shows "result is undefined".such that is in for loop,see my code                                                            success : function(response) {
   if(response.status == "Success"){
    $('#info').html(successMsg);
    $('#info').show('slow');
    $('#error').hide();
     }else{
                     var errorInfo = "";
                     for(var i =0 ; i < response.result.length ; i++){

Comment: Make a new question for that. Because this has nothing to do with this question and SO is not intended to answer questions in comments.

Comment: But please answer my answer as solution so this question is completed

Comment: K k but the POST URL is not working,it shows "error[object:Object]"while give the url:api/rolepermissions/updprm and also trien with url:/api/... And Surly i will mark solutions for you.